# Azure DevOps rest api get release definition does not include variables

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I wrote a little PowerShell script that get's a release definition. On that definition I defined a few variables. Both with scope release as well as with a scope to a specific environment. When I now get the definition these variables are not included. The end goal is to be able to change a variable value using the API.

*** Update ***

Merlin Liang was completely right. I just didn't print the results correctly.

Here's my code for anyone else with the same :

```bsh
$VariableValue = "test"
$VariableName = "test"

## Construct a basic auth head using PAT
function BasicAuthHeader()
{
    $ba = (":{0}" -f $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)
    $ba = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ba)
    $ba = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($ba)
    $h = @{Authorization=("Basic{0}" -f $ba);ContentType="application/json"}

    return $h
}

$h = BasicAuthHeader 
$baseRMUri = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI + $env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT
$releaseId = $env:RELEASE_RELEASEID

$getReleaseUri = $baseRMUri + "/_apis/release/definitions/30?api-version=5.1"

$release = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $getReleaseUri -Headers $h -Method Get
# write-host "results = $($release | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

$release2 = $release | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | ConvertFrom-JSON

$release2.variables.($VariableName).value = $VariableValue

$release2 = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(($release2 | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100))

$updateReleaseUri = $baseRMUri + "/_apis/release/definitions/30?api-version=5.1"

$content2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateReleaseUri -Method Put -Headers $h -ContentType "application/json" -Body $release2 -Verbose -Debug
```

Comment: Are you using Azure DevOps? TFS? If TFS, what version of TFS? Variables are included in release definitions, although be aware that **secrets** are blank.

Comment: I am using Azure DevOps and the variables are not secrets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify the last line of your script as:

```
write-host "results = $($release | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

Then you would see the detailed definition from its result.

---

When we give the corresponding response to API, in fact, it is a nested array. This means if you just use `Write-Host $result` to print out the response, then it can only give you the first level.

You must use `ConvertTo-Json -Depth ***` to convert the response firstly(`ConvertTo-Json`), and then specify how many levels of contained objects in JSON you want them show out(`-Depth ***`).

Here, in your issue, the corresponding has been replied, but they were hide because of nested. So, just need to **spread out the nested arrays/objects** by using above script.

Comment: You are totally right! After I did that, the variables were nicely shown. Thanks!

Comment: @E.Staal, Welcome:-) , you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

I am using `https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.1` and variables and variableGroups are included.

Comment: Can you add a Fiddler request-response to compare for differences... PAT excluded.

Comment: I have added the output from my powershell Invoke-RestMehthod command to my question. That will also do I think?